# Running Assembly Code on Mac by using vs code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, assembly, irvine32

When I try to run assembly code in vs code I encounter a problem as shown in the image below:
[image]

I try many extension but to no avail, I also try (Amiga Assembly) extension But I got another problem as shown in the image below:
[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem, and how to run assembly code on mac by using vs code

Comment: Are you trying to write a (16-bit real mode) DOS program?  Or is VSCode mis-using the term "DOS" to describe Windows text-console programs?  I can see an Irvine32.inc include behind the error message in your screenshot, and Irvine32 is a library for 32-bit x86 Windows, not actual DOS.  (Not Amiga either!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution of this problem. If anyone has the same problem, try this solution. It may work for you.

First thing I download extension called (MASM/TASM)
[image]

Finally, Right-Click in your code then click (Run ASM code) as shown in the image below:
[image]

I hope this solution helped you

Comment: You're not writing a DOS program; Irvine32 is 32-bit code for native Windows executables.  Note the use of a 32-bit pointer in `mov edx, OFFSET myMessage`, and see https://asmirvine.com/gettingStartedVS2017/index.htm  It is MASM syntax, but the documentation you screenshotted for that MASM/TASM plugin says it's only for running under DOS, not Win32.  Also, what good is a screenshot without a link?  Don't screenshot text in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a specific extension for Mac Assembler. I'd recommend using VSCode as your editor and [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) with custom commands.

Alternatively, you could use the terminal pane to manually execute the Mac OSX assembler commands.

Here's a link to the [as command reference from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/Assembler.pdf). It'll probably be a useful reference for compiling and linking.

Comment: The OP didn't say so, but we can see from their screenshot they're using the Irvine32 library to write a 32-bit x86 Windows program, presumably to run in a text console window if they're using the normal functions like ReadDec and WriteHex.  That also implies MASM / JWASM syntax, so they won't be able to assemble it with the native MacOS assembler; GNU `.intel_syntax noprefix` has similar instruction syntax but different directives.  (Your answer is potentially useful to other future readers writing Mac programs on their Mac, though, using syntax that native Mac tools can assemble.)